# Azure AD B2C Audience validation failed

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, .net-6.0

I'm trying to authenticate to my B2C AD tenant on Azure AD B2C. I'm using OAuth 2.0 on aspnet .NET 6

If I request a new bearer token using Client Id

*0fdd4f3b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-3f84bd9d02ax*

I get back an **aud** value

*https://mysite.onmicrosoft.com/0fdd4f3b-xxxx-xxxx-a438-3f84bd9d02ax*

I'm using

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

If I use *0fdd4f3b-xxxx-xxxx-a438-3f84bd9d02ax* in my config, he tries to validate it by prefixing Client ID with **api://** and the following exception:

> IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'https://mysite.onmicrosoft.com/0fdd4f3b-xxxx-xxxx-a438-3f84bd9d02ax'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'api://0fdd4f3b-xxxx-xxxx-a438-3f84bd9d02ax'

If I use *https://mysite.onmicrosoft.com/0fdd4f3b-xxxx-xxxx-a438-3f84bd9d02ax* in my config, he tries to validate it by prefixing Client ID with **api://** and the following exception:

> IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'https://mysite.onmicrosoft.com/0fdd4f3b-xxxx-xxxx-a438-3f84bd9d02ax'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'api://https://mysite.onmicrosoft.com/0fdd4f3b-xxxx-xxxx-a438-3f84bd9d02ax'

Why is the value always prefixed with **api://** ?

Comment: That's the default that "regular" Azure AD generates for the App ID URI at least. You should be able to override the valid audiences to set the one that is valid for you.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, apparently Stack Overflow was my rubber ducky.

If your Application ID URI does not start with **api://** you'll have to make a manual change to the manifest of your application and switch to access tokens version 2.

[image: Manifest link]

Then change the value of *accessTokenAcceptedVersion* from *null* to **2**

Now you can go back to your local application configuration and set the value of ClientId to the GUID only not including https://xxx.onmicrosoft.com/.